# How can I assign a set of values to a string or Int value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, html-agility-pack

I have a problem with C#. 
I managed it to parse out the price of a material from a web page (with a list of materials and prices) but I don't know exactly how I can extract single values to single strings or ints. I have assigned the "price" to a string but it this string contains a array of values.

Here's the C# Code:

```cs
var products = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("id", "")
                .Equals("accordion1")).ToList();

            var productListItems = products[0].Descendants("tr")
                .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("data-name", "")
                .Contains("")).ToList();

            foreach (var productListItem in productListItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(productListItem.GetAttributeValue("data-name", ""));
                var tds = productListItem.Descendants("td").ToList();

                var name = tds[0].InnerText;
                var price = tds[1].InnerText.Trim('$');

                Console.WriteLine(name);
                Console.WriteLine(price);
            }
```

Console:

```
clay_r
Lehm
199

coal_r
Kohle
427

copper_r
Kupfer
312

etc.
```

Now I want, that I can call a single material (like clay) with a single string. So that I have for every materialPrice a int.

Something like:

```cs
int clayPrice = int.Parse(the first price)
int coalPrice = int.Parse(the second price)
int copperPrice = int.Parse(the third price)
```

etc.

I'm pretty new to C#, so I don't know much about it. I hope someone understands my problem and can help me.

Comment: You should probably look into creating a separate class to hold all of the info for each item. Right now you're kinda working with the data disjointly and as you can see, it's more troublesome to keep related into "linked" together.

Comment: Are the string and int assigned to "price" separated by line break? Is it the same pattern in all rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define a separate class that contains the pricing information.
   For example:

   ```
   public class PriceInfo
   {
      public string Name {get; set;}
      public string RawPrice {get; set;}
      public int Price => int.Parse(RawPrice.Trim('$'));
   }
   ```
2. Define a Dictionary as a class member. [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8).

   ```
   Dictionary<string, PriceInfo> priceData = new Dictionary<string, PriceInfo>();
   ```
3. In your loop, add the prices to the dictionary.

   ```
   foreach (var productListItem in productListItems)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(productListItem.GetAttributeValue("data-name", ""));
       var tds = productListItem.Descendants("td").ToList();

       var name = tds[0].InnerText;
       var price = tds[1].InnerText;

       // add to Dictionary
       priceData[name] = new PriceInfo
       {
         Name = name,
         RawPrice = price
       };
   }
   ```
4. Use the value:

   ```
   priceData["somename"].Price
   ```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is, that I cant really manage to import this without any error messages. I don't expect that from you, but it would be a really big help if you would take a look, and edit it...
https://docs.google.com/document/d/194cKZR1d_hZkBZtYp_ARc-_WjHczl8grwh6RX-49Wpw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Or this, if you want to download it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19cvC0opzIYQgRQkN8TAa7TzalcUK9xkX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can't declare a variable in the namespace. It needs to be a part of the class.